# Data not accessible outside the subscribe method in hello data log

Tags: angular

```
getMemberInformation() {

  let url = "http://abc/abc/xyz";
  return this._http.get(url, xhrRequestOptions()).map(
     data => {
               return JSON.stringify(data);
          })
 }}
```

myRequestResponse: any;

```
ngOnInit() {
  this._AnotherClass.getMemberInformation().subscribe(data => console.log('Data Level 0:',data));
  this._AnotherClass.getMemberInformation().subscribe(data => this.myRequestResponse = data);
  console.log('Data Level 1:', this.myRequestResponse);
```

=========After edit the code data is coming on data level 0 log, but data lever 1 do not show the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's by design. The data is only available when the function passed to `subscribe(...)`

```ts
data => this.getMyCarsFromServer = JSON.stringify(data)
```

was called.

Just change the code to

```ts
.subscribe(
              data => {
                this.getMyCarsFromServer = JSON.stringify(data); // put the data returned from the server in our variable
                console.log('hello data', this.getMyCarsFromServer);
              },
              error => console.log("Error HTTP GET Service"), // in case of failure show this message
              () => console.log("Job Done Get !", this.getMyCarsFromServer)//run this code in all cases
         );
```

You can change `.subscribe()` to `.map()`, then an `Observable` is returned instead of a `Subscription` and the caller can subscribe.

```ts
someMethod() {
    return this.someService.someObservable.map(
              data => {
                //this.getMyCarsFromServer = JSON.stringify(data); // put the data returned from the server in our variable
                // console.log('hello data', this.getMyCarsFromServer);
                return JSON.stringify(data);
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.log("Error HTTP GET Service"); // in case of failure show this message
                throw error;
                // or 
                return Observable.throw();
                // or
                return Observable.of([]);
              })
              .finally(() => console.log("Job Done Get !", this.getMyCarsFromServer);//run this code in all cases
}
```

```ts
this.someMethod().subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Hello data is printed well
But when i am trying to access getMyCarsFromServer  outside the subscribe function to get the data and to use the data, it is not accessable.
Please give hint so that i can use the data coming inside the getMyCarsFromServer

Comment: I updated my answer. You don't need the `catch` and `finally` stuff, I just translated it from your original code. Important is what the callback passed to `.map(...)` returns. This is what the subscriber will get.

Comment: Hard to tell. Where or how are you checking if it's working? You can't check after `this.someMethod().subscribe(data => this.getMyCarsFromServer = data);` because this would be the same as in your question. Add `{{getMyCarsFromServer | json}}` to the template of your component and check if it shows anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126510/discussion-between-vijay-gupta-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: this._memberDemographicsService.getMemberInformation().subscribe(data => console.log('Data Level 0:',data));
      this._memberDemographicsService.getMemberInformation().subscribe(data => this.myRequestResponse = data);
      console.log('Data Level 1:', this.myRequestResponse);                         Level 0 log is printing but level 1 log is not printing

Comment: That doesn't sound like it's related to the code in your question. Can you please edit your question and add the code there (code in comments is quite hard to read) and add the code of `memberDemographicService`

Comment: You again have `console.log()` outside of `subscribe()`. This code is executed before `data => this.myRequestResponse = data`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but finally i need the data into the varaible plz help

Comment: `this.myRequestResponse = data` **does** write it into a variable but ` console.log('Data Level 1:', this.myRequestResponse);` is executed before `this.myRequestResponse = data` is executed. If you need to access the variable when it has the value, you need to move the code into `subscribe(...)`